# Is there anyway i can append /concat an element to an enumerable if condition?

Tags: c#, linq, monads

Hello i am trying to select all unique types inside an object recursively.Is there any way i not use the  `new Type[]{ }` stuff or the ternary operator?

```
class Con 
{
    public int a;
}
class Right 
{
    public Con x;
    public int a;
    public double b;
}

public static HashSet<Type> TypeHash = new HashSet<Type>();

public static IEnumerable<Type> Traverse(Type enclosingType) 
{
    return (enclosingType.IsPrimitive) 
        ? new Type[] { TypeHash.Add(enclosingType) ? enclosingType : null } 
        : enclosingType.GetFields().AsEnumerable()
            .SelectMany(fieldinfo => Traverse(fieldinfo.FieldType)
                .Concat(new Type[] { (TypeHash.Add(fieldinfo.FieldType)) ? fieldinfo.FieldType : null }));
}


static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    Con myconnect = new Con { a = 5 };
    var c = Traverse(new Right { a = 2, b = 3 }.GetType()).Where(x=>x!=null).ToList();
}
```

I would need something like :

case primitive type: `yield return type`
case not primitive type: `Enclosingtype.GetFields().SelectMany(field=>Traverse(field.fieldtype)`

Of course I need it to be unique too that is why i used the HashSet.

Comment: What do you mean with escape?

Comment: I wanted to know if i can avoid it.If the element does not satisfy the condition i would like to know if there is anything similar to string.empty but for enumerables.

Comment: Yes, use `yield return` instead of LINQ.

Comment: Well with Linq i would use yield for when i reach the primitive type (string ,double etc..) but then i would need to return the resulting sequence for the other case.

Comment: Can you yield return for a case and return simple for the other case? It seems it is not doable? What i want to do is :  If element is primitive type =>yield return element type, else return selectmany on traverse of fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> Traverse(Type enclosingType)
{
    if (enclosingType.IsPrimitive) // string is not a primitive... think about this condition again
    {
        yield return enclosingType;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var type in enclosingType.GetFields().SelectMany(f => Traverse(f.FieldType)))
        {
            yield return type;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var result = new HashSet<Type>(Traverse(typeof(Right)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this ! It is what i needed.I didn't think to use Traverse inside the Hashset constructor.